# How to create a copy of sheet in a target folder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I have a script which creates a copy of the sheets file in the root folder itself but I would prefer the new file to be placed into a different folder, and also to pop up to indicate the new file has been created, the new file name should only end with a date stamp (DD/MM/YYYY) no time stamp required.

I have added the target folder id in the 
`drive.makeCopy(fileName, 'Taget location id');` 
and this does not work

```
function dialog() {  
    var data = '<input type="button" value="Create A Copy" onclick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(openfile).copyDoc();"><script>function openfile(url) {window.open(url);}</script>';
    var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(data);  
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'New Form - Click here');
} 
function copyDoc() { 
    var drive=DriveApp.getFileById('fileid'); 
    var timestamp = new Date().toISOString().replace("T", " ").split(".")[0];  
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
    var file = DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId());  
    var fileName = ('filename - '+timestamp); 
    drive.makeCopy(fileName); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy file to an exact location, you should specify the destination argument when invoking `.makeCopy()` method and the destination must be a `Folder` instance, [not its Id](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#makeCopy(String,Folder)). Furthermore, if you want to then open a file, your server-side function should [explicitly return](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#success_handlers) something (in your case, a file Url).

Just modify your code a bit at the end:

```
var destination = DriveApp.getFolderById('yourFolderId');
var copy = drive.makeCopy(fileName,destination);
return copy.getUrl();
```

Btw, it is best practice nowadays to add event listeners programmatically:

```
function openfile(url) { 
  window.open(url); 
}

var input = document.querySelector('input[type=button]');
    input.addEventListener('click',function(event){
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(openfile).copyDoc();
    });
```